# Getting information from two tables that are in relation

Tags: sql, linq, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to display the information of two tables that have a relationship inside a grid view?

For example, the name student and profile of table 1

And their Absent student from Table 2

And we'll display the information of both together at the same time in a grid view. I'm glad to be a beginner.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFptY.jpg

Comment: In SQL you can use JOIN. Just google SQL JOINS and should get alot of stuff to read about it\

Comment: you can type code for me. i am beginer

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl_Gheybat, InfoStudent WHERE Tbl_Gheybat.IdForenKey = InfoStudent.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build up a new `ViewModel`to be displayed at the `gridview`

For example: let say you have a two classes in relation with each other `Student` and `AbsentStudent` in your code you will create a new `ViewModel` class and fill in the data you want to display in the grid

Comment: There is no other solution؟؟؟

Comment: I think this is the easiest solution, or you can add a new property to the main domain  with the value you want and map it in your query. then display it normally but make sure its not database mapped to avoid conflict with database operations.

Comment: one question. then i can insert or update on the viewMode

Comment: what do you mean by you can insert or update on the viewmodel? 

View Model is a model class that can hold only those properties that is required for a view. It can also contains properties from more than one entities (tables) of the database. As the name suggests, this model is created specific to the View requirements. as per the following 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc'

Comment: if this was helpful answer for you please mark it as an answer